# How to add space between string and numbers in specific lines in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file consists of columns like below:

```
1- 23MOL C10001 2.840 1.154 3.818
2- 23MOL H10002 2.821 1.256 3.850
3- 23MOL H10003 2.907 1.106 3.889
4- 23MOL H10004 2.884 1.156 3.719
5- 23MOL O10005 2.824 0.912 3.732
6- 23MOL C10006 2.600 0.726 3.702
7- 23MOL H10007 2.684 0.677 3.751
```

I want to read the file and  add space between strings(H,O,C,N and ...) and numbers in column 2 for lines 4 to 6.I want to have result like below:

```
1- 23MOL C10001 2.840 1.154 3.818
2- 23MOL H10002 2.821 1.256 3.850
3- 23MOL H10003 2.907 1.106 3.889
4- 23MOL H 10004 2.884 1.156 3.719
5- 23MOL O 10005 2.824 0.912 3.732
6- 23MOL C 10006 2.600 0.726 3.702
7- 23MOL H 10007 2.684 0.677 3.751
```

I wrote this code:

```py
import re
s = open ("text.txt").read()[4:-1] # from line 5 to one before the last line
REG = r'(\S+\s\S+\s[A-Z])(.*)'
new_data = re.sub(REG, r'\1 \2', s) 
print(new_data)
```

It reads the file, but It didn't separate letters from numbers. What is not working?

Comment: `read()` returns a single string, not a list of lines. So `4:-1` is from character 5 to the 2nd-to-last character. You want `readlines()`

Comment: And then you need to loop through all the lines, or join them back into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
import re 

with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(3, len(lines)):
    lines[i] = re.sub(r'(\S+\s\S+\s[A-Z])(.*)', r'\1 \2', lines[i])

print(''.join(lines))
```

Output :

```
1- 23MOL C10001 2.840 1.154 3.818
2- 23MOL H10002 2.821 1.256 3.850
3- 23MOL H10003 2.907 1.106 3.889
4- 23MOL H 10004 2.884 1.156 3.719
5- 23MOL O 10005 2.824 0.912 3.732
6- 23MOL C 10006 2.600 0.726 3.702
7- 23MOL H 10007 2.684 0.677 3.751
```